# How to get aggregate results from generic map?

Tags: apex, aggregateresult

How can I get the Orders values from the following generic map?

```
Map<Id, Account> ordersByAccountIdMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Orders) FROM Account]);

Map<Id, SObject> sObjectMap = (Map<Id, SObject>)ordersByAccountIdMap;

// I need something as follows
System.debug('TEST: ' + sObjectMap.get('0018E00000uM2xMQAS').get('Orders'));
```

Note: it has to work in a generic map since all the maps that I will be working on will have the Orders aggregation result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `getSobjects` method for this purpose in the base Sobject class. See the documentation [Sobject Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) for detailed information.

In your case:

```
List<Sobject> orders = sObjectMap.get('0018E00000uM2xMQAS').getSobjects('Orders');
```

Answer (score 0):

We can process aggregate query result like below example:

```
Map<Id, Account> ordersByAccountIdMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Orders) FROM Account]);

for(String key: ordersByAccountIdMap.keyset()){
    System.debug('Test: '+ordersByAccountIdMap.get(key).Orders);
}
```

More details: [Working with SOQL Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm)

Comment: I know this trick but I need the generic version. Fortunately, @Keith c provided a nice answer.